# How can I get the drive that the currently running python file is in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want to know the drive that my python file is in because `os.abspath()` doesn't give me that and I haven't found any other possibility.

Comment: What about `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific; what OS are you on and with drive do you mean physical drive or logical partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different function of the os package.

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is to use:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

or to get the current working directory you can use the following:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.getcwd()`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
path/to/folder
```

or simply just print `__file__`:

```
>>> __file__
path/to/folder/file.py
```